# Where exactly is the page rendered, even with 'use client'?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, react-server-components

My understanding was that in NextJS13, If you do 'use client', the page is rendered on the client, just like with classic React.
and yet, even with 'use client' stated clearly, If I try to use some client side features - In my case I use Redux and do rendering based on values I get from the Store - I get the error:

> Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

This can be resolved by using UseEffect on the top of the export function., as the documentation suggests. Now - it does work well, UseEffect does move all the rendering to the client - but my question is more about NextJS internals: why 'use client' doesn't  seem to move all rendering to the client? Are there different levels of client renderings, maybe...?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

when a client component inside a server component, both components get rendered on the server. I can prove it to you. Let's say you have `app/server/page.tsx` and `app/client/page.tsx` file:

```
import { ClientComponent } from "../client/page";

export default async function ServerComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClientComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is client component:

```
"use client";

export function ClientComponent() {
  console.log("I am client component");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>I AM CLIENT COMPONENT</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

if you look at the terminal, you will see `console.log("I am client component")` this gets printed.

or if you go to `/server` route and click on `Network Tab` on chrome tools:

[image]

you see the we make a request to `/server` route which is server component and it renders the client component on the server