# Why am I getting a server side rendering error when I specifically set component to be rendered on client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component that is supposed to be rendered on client side but I get an error in the terminal stating that it cannot read `localStorage` because it is undefined and that happens because the app is trying to render it on the server. Heres the code where in the first line I set rendering to be on the client side

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import chevron from "../public/icons/chevron.png";
export default function LanguageSwitch() {
    let lang: string | null = null;

    const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);
    lang = localStorage?.getItem("lang");

    const handleLanguage = () => {
        localStorage?.setItem('lang', lang ? lang == 'SRB' ? 'ENG' : 'SRB' : 'ENG')
    }

    return (
        <div className="language-switch" onClick={() => setOpenMenu(p => !p)} >
            <p className="menu-item">{lang ?? "SRB"}</p>
            <Image src={chevron} alt="" />
            <div>
                {openMenu && <p onClick={handleLanguage} className="menu-item language-select">
                    {lang ? (lang == "SRB" ? "ENG" : "SRB") : "ENG"}
                </p>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the error:

```
 ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

I'm using Next.js 13.

Comment: do  check if typeof window and inside acces localstorage?

Comment: Hi Brimstone! Is your question solved? Let us know please.

Answer (score 0):

when a client component inside a server component, both components get rendered on the server. [Where exactly is the page rendered, even with 'use client'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77001100/where-exactly-is-the-page-rendered-even-with-use-client/77546601#77546601)

that is why you should still be adding a guard

```
 if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.localStorage) {
    // here you can access to localstorage
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Client Components, with `use client` also render first on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76301770/15288641). So no browser specific API should be called in the component body. It should be only in event handlers, `useEffect` callbacks…

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { use, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import chevron from "../public/icons/chevron.png";
export default function LanguageSwitch() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLang(localStorage?.getItem("lang"));
  }, []);

  const handleLanguage = () => {
    localStorage?.setItem("lang", lang ? (lang == "SRB" ? "ENG" : "SRB") : "ENG");
  };

  if (!lang) {
    <div>Loadding...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="language-switch" onClick={() => setOpenMenu((p) => !p)}>
      <p className="menu-item">{lang ?? "SRB"}</p>
      <Image src={chevron} alt="" />
      <div>
        {openMenu && (
          <p onClick={handleLanguage} className="menu-item language-select">
            {lang ? (lang == "SRB" ? "ENG" : "SRB") : "ENG"}
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`typeof window !== "undefined"` is a hack that would, most likely, lead to a [hydration error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error).